# Delay application close and make an send a message

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

Actually i have a **TCP Client** that onStart connect to the server and send the device IP and number to it, but now i want that when the application is getting closed ( onDestroy ) delay it for some seconds ( the right time to reopen the connection and send another message ) and send another message in which i'm saying that the device is offline.

I've tryed to do it onDestroy method but probably it's madness and obviously
that didn't worked ( i tryed to do the following stuff onDestroy :

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    new ConnectTask().execute("");
    if (client != null) {
        client.sendMessage(trm + "OFFLINE");
    }
    if (client != null) {
        client.stopClient();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
    server.onDestroy();
}
```

Here is my **MainActivity** code where i evocate the TCP Client and sending start message:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Server server;
static Client client;
settings Settings;
public static TextView terminale, indr, msg;
TextView log;
static TextView msgServer;
static String ipp;
static String trm;
static DataBaseHandler myDB;
allert Allert;
SharedPreferences prefs;
String s1 = "GAB Tamagnini SRL © 2017 \n" +
        "Via Beniamino Disraeli, 17,\n" +
        "42124 Reggio Emilia \n" +
        "Telefono: 0522 / 38 32 22 \n" +
        "Fax: 0522 / 38 32 72 \n" +
        "Partita IVA, Codice Fiscale \n" +
        "Reg. Impr. di RE 00168780351 \n" +
        "Cap. soc. € 50.000,00 i.v. \n" + "" +
        "REA n. RE-107440 \n" +
        "presso C.C.I.A.A. di Reggio Emilia";
ImageButton settings, helps, allerts, home;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Utils.darkenStatusBar(this, R.color.colorAccent);
    server = new Server(this);
    myDB = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(this);

    msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log_avviso);
    settings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.impo);
    helps = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aiut);
    allerts = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.msge);
    home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gab);
    terminale = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terminal);
    indr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.indr);
    msgServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverMSG);

    final Cursor cursor = myDB.fetchData();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            indr.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            terminale.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            Client.SERVER_IP = cursor.getString(1);
            trm = cursor.getString(2);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,FinalizingOperationsService.class));

    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    ipp = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());

    startConnection.postDelayed(runnableConnection,5000);
    startMessage.postDelayed(runnableMessage,5500);

    cursor.close();
    server.Parti();


    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                                    counter++;
                                    if (counter == 10) {
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                        builder.setCancelable(true);
                                        builder.setMessage(s1);
                                        builder.show();
                                        counter = 0;
                                    }
        }
    });

    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent impostazioni = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), settingsLogin.class);
            startActivity(impostazioni);
        }
    });

    helps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent pgHelp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), help.class);
            startActivity(pgHelp);
        }
    });

    allerts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Server.count = 0;
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
            msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Intent pgAlert = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), allert.class);
            startActivity(pgAlert);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    server.onDestroy();
}

public static class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Client> {

    @Override
    protected Client doInBackground(String... message) {


        client = new Client(new Client.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override

            public void messageReceived(String message) {

                publishProgress(message);

            }
    });
        client.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            msgServer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
            msgServer.setText("ONLINE");

        Log.d("test", "response " + values[0]);
    }
}

static Handler startConnection = new Handler();
static Runnable runnableConnection = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        new ConnectTask().execute("");
    }
};

static Handler startMessage = new Handler();
static Runnable runnableMessage = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Cursor cursor = myDB.fetchData();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Client.SERVER_IP = cursor.getString(1);
                trm = cursor.getString(2);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (client != null) {
            client.sendMessage(ipp + "#" + trm);
        }
    }
};

static Handler startMessageClose = new Handler();
static Runnable runnableMessageClose = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (client != null) {
            client.sendMessage(trm + "IS OFFLINE");
        }
        }
    };


}
```

The right command for open the connection is `new ConnectTask().execute("");`
while i'm sending the message with `if (client != null) { client.sendMessage(ipp + "#" + trm); }`

**FinalizingOperationsService.java code:**

```
public class FinalizingOperationsService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("FOService", "Service Started");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("FOService", "Service Destroyed");
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.e("FOService", "Service Ends");
    MainActivity.startConnection.removeCallbacks(MainActivity.runnableConnection);
    MainActivity.startConnection.postDelayed(MainActivity.runnableConnection,100);

    MainActivity.startMessageClose.removeCallbacks(MainActivity.runnableMessageClose);
    MainActivity.startMessageClose.postDelayed(MainActivity.runnableMessageClose,110);

    stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new service like this,

```
public class FinalizingOperationsService extends Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.d("FOService", "Service Started");
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.d("FOService", "Service Destroyed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            Log.e("FOService", "Service Ends");
            // write server updation code here
            // after completing code perform stopself() to stop this service;
        }
    }
```

And define this service in manifest file like this,

```
<service android:name=". FinalizingOperationsService" android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

Finally start service in onCreate method of your main activity

`startService(newIntent(getContext(),FinalizingOperationsService.class));`

**Explanation:**
onTaskRemoved() method of the service is called when application is killed or destroyed, so in this method you can perform your final operations to notify server and stop your service after operations done. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I just tryed to do it but seems nothing changed, i've updated the question with the FInalizingOperationsService code and updated MainActivity can you have a look at it?

Comment: i think you lose the reference of your Client when app is shutdown, you should have to reinitialize your client in a service to do those operations.

Comment: wait but did i have to create a new class for the FinalizingOperationsService? or i can do it in MainActivity? because for reinitialize the i have to recopy all the async method from the Main

Comment: its better to create a separate class to initialize your client.

Comment: actually i reinitialized the Client in the FinalizingOperationsService but application still close without sending the message or also initializing the Client that just close it immediatly...

Comment: Still same logs as the old i mean there is nothing new in it and there is no logs from FinalizingOperationsService

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149557/discussion-between-androidgeek-and-i-mytyuk).